# CSS and JavaScript files not loading on Stack Exchange

Tags: support, status-completed

What is going on with stackexchange tonight?  I am able log in from one of the three machines I tried to log in from, and not from the other two, where the format is messed up  and there are no open-id buttons to choose to click on in order to log in.  Same messed up format when I look at meta on this present machine, but I logged in before going to meta.

Comment: A screenshot would probably be very helpful.

Comment: I see no problems; from time to time I have trouble with this (and other sites) due to connection problems, but as far as I can tell they have to do with my internet connection rather than the sites...

Comment: Now it seems to be normal.  For about an hour it wasn't.  I tried it both from my home computer and from a machine at Hamline University, with the same results, although it was working from a machine at the University of Minnesota.

Comment: This should be fixed now. Are you still having issues?